# Retrieve items from a SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I have searched this question on the web but to no result that fits my problem.

I am trying to retrive a specific colum in a sharepoint online list and comparing it to the currently logged in user. this is my code so far.

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext((HttpContext));

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                var user = GetUser(clientContext);
                var items = LoadList(clientContext);

                foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
                {
                    if (user.Title == listItem["Author"].ToString())
                    {
                        //Do stuff later
                    }
                }

            }
        }

     public ListItemCollection LoadList(ClientContext context)
    {
        List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Arbetsplan");
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return items;
    }

    public User GetUser(ClientContext context)
    {
        var user = context.Web.CurrentUser;
        context.Load(user);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        return user;
    }
```

The error I get is like this:

[image]

The 
`Author` column is of type
`Person or Group`. I have an idea that that's where the problem is. I am not handling the type correctly?

The Author field in the SharePoint list is named "Created By". But to reach it I have to use the intrenal name.[image]

Comment: Possibly but I dont see Author or the properties of the author.. so its hard to tell..

Comment: That's not an exception, that's the list item's properties. The debugger cannot load them, because it has no notion of sharepoint context to do so (you probably know you have to load everything in CSOM before accessing it). So, what is your exception/error exactly?

Comment: i am sorry. I am very new to the CSOM model and Sharepoint Online. What I know is that I have to load what I want to use and the execute the query. and then use what I get back. I am not currently familiar with if I have to load in any other way then I have shown in my code. Do you know what I should do for the debugger to have a notion of the SharePoint list properties?

Comment: I dont have any errors in the error list.